# Spring-Batch Invalid JobExecution, ID not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am trying to run few `spring-batch` jobs in a loop. Some of the jobs gets successfully completed. But others do not , and the below exception is thrown in the logs:

```
<ERROR> [org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob] :Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.NoSuchObjectException: **Invalid JobExecution, ID <theid> not found.**
        at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.updateJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:197)
        at
```

**The applicationContext.xml has the below configurations:**

```
<beans:bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="databaseType" value="POSTGRES" />
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <beans:property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager" >
    <beans:property name="dataSource"
    ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Also have the below configuration in the applicationContext.xml

 `<aop:config>
  <aop:advisor
   pointcut="execution(* org.springframework.batch.core..*Repository+.*(..))"
   advice-ref="txAdvice" />
 </aop:config>
 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
  <tx:attributes>
   <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRES_NEW" rollback-for="Throwable"/>
  </tx:attributes>
 </tx:advice>`

Comment: Are you sure spring batch tables is not getting deleted at some point of time while running jobs in loop ?

Comment: If the error message displayed is "NoSuchObjectException: Invalid JobExecution, ID 30399 not found"
then the entry in **sub_job_execution**  table  has **job_execution_id** column as 30399 and **exit_message** column as the error message stack trace

Comment: When you say you are running jobs in loop , what do you mean by that ? Are you waiting for the previous job to get completed before you start the next one . If that is not the case then I believe isolation-level-for-create is causing the problem . By default it is serializable in spring batch and you night want to change it to some other level like read committed etc..

Comment: We are running jobs in  in the pattern  (10 jobs + sleep +20  sleep + 20 sleep ) repeating the same. 
No, we are not waiting for the jobs to complete.
isolationLevelForCreate is ISOLATION_DEFAULT, and the underlying database islation level is **read committed**

Comment: If you checks the logs , by default spring batch changes the isolation-level-for-create to serializable , which means not just the row but entire table wil bel locked when one thread is doing some update , meantime if other thread is trying to access it ,it will be not be accessible .I believe underlying db isolation level does not matter , I would suggest you to change the isolation level in the spring batch config and see if it works for you.

Comment: We have tried setting the isolationLevelForCreate to  ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED , even with this configuration its giving the same exception.